# How to configure the network interface for FreeBSD install?

Tags: installation, unix, freebsd

First off I'm a FreeBSD noob, but I've done quite a bit of Debian/Ubuntu/Redhat.

I'm trying to install FreeBSD off of a thumb drive and when I go through the standard install, it asks where to source the to-be-installed files from.

I select FTP and some FTP server, then it asks for my network configuration. 
It asks whether it should try DHCP and not matter if I say yes or no, it will go to a blank network configuration page where i am asked for:
hostname, domain, ipv4 gateway, name server, [(plip0 congid) IPv4 address, netmask, extra options].

I have tried all sorts of things, but it's not accepting them. I figure I don't need to set the domain since I'm on a home network and I set the gateway to the router's IP address. I have also tried to give it the IP address my router assigns it, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if dhcp shoots you there, it sounds like your network driver isn't on the install media you are using

Comment: hmm any idea how i can get the driver on the install?

Comment: i located a external dvd drive so ill give the DVD image a shot